# Can't find my Ubuntu partition after laptop crashed

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, windows

My laptop crashed last week and as a first step, I reinstalled the hatefulness that is Windows 7.

Now I can't see my Ubuntu partition but when I try to install the new version of Ubuntu, I get a message asking if I want to uninstall.  This suggests to me that my Ubuntu partition is hiding somewhere!

Can anyone help please?

I can't be absolutely certain as I've been using Ubuntu for a while now but I think I had version 11.10 running.

Answer (score 0):

By installing Windows you erased the Ubuntu partition.

My guess to why it's asking to uninstall Ubuntu upon the installation, is that GRUB still lives on your hard disk.

So if you want to install Ubuntu just skip the uninstall question.